# How to Configure Google app engine Java project when using third party libraries like spring

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to configure applications that use Spring MVC for GAE Java. Is there an
article which gives this information?

More specifically I would like to know if I am required to upload spring
related jars also to the cloud? How do I need to configure my application if I needn't upload these jars?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the horses mouth:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/d93fd7385bf85bf7

Answer (score 0):

I believe my [jappstart](http://jappstart.com) project would be helpful to you. It is working example of a Spring application on GAE. It also provides pom.xml for building and deploying to App Engine via Maven.